# SQL query statement with condition and count

Tags: sql-server, database, join, select

I have two tables, one is Project and another is Participant, the Project_ID in participant table is the foreign key of Project table. Project_Manager is the status flag of a project manager, when a participant is the project manager, that filed will be 1.

Project table:

```
Project
----------
Project_ID (primiry key)
Project_Name
```

Participant table:

```
Participant
----------
Participant_ID (primiry key)
First_Name
Last_Name
Email
Project_Manager
Projecct_ID (foreign key)
```

My question is if is it possible in one query statement that I can get the count of participant in a given project ID and the manager name of that project as well as the project name.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join and aggregate:

```
select 
    pr.project_name,
    pa.project_id, 
    count(*) no_participants,
    max(case when pa.project_manager = 1 then pa.last_name end) manager_last_name
from participant pa
inner join project pr on pr.project_id = pa.project_id
group by pa.project_id
```

Comment: It works only with last name. How can I get the full name instead of last name only? I mean is it possible I can concat first_name and last_name together as full_name. Now, I can follow your logic and add another case when then end for first_name, but it's better return a full_name rather than seperate I expect.

Comment: @Moon: you need to concat within the `max()`, like: `max(case when pa.project_manager = 1 then concat(pa.first_name, ' ', pa.last_name) end) as manager_last_name`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(1) NUMBERS,PA.PROJECT_MANAGER,PR.PROJECT_NAME 
FROM PARTICIPENT PA INNER JOIN PROJECT PR 
ON PA.PROJECT_ID = PR.PROJECT_ID 
WHERE PA.PROJECT_ID =100 
GROUP BY PR.PROJECT_NAME,PA.PROJECT_MANAGER
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Hi Donald Duck, Your suggestion is valid one and I totally accept your recommendation... As well, I saw your answers too as sample... Those are too good and way your explanation is user friendly.